# broken icons with faenza theme

Tags: 12.10, faenza

I just installed ubuntu 12.10 but i have an issue
I installed faenza icon theme with this way : http://handytutorial.com/install-faenza-icons-ubuntu-12-10/

But when i switch to faenza theme from gnome tweak tool some icons are broken. For example i attach screenshots :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eem1k.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/InZLZ.png]

Any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faenza was not updated for a long time, some icons are missing from the package. But don't worry, it is very easy to fix this issue.

You will have to edit faenza index.theme. You can find it in Faenza icon folder, e.g. /usr/share/icons/Faenza.

1. Open it as root

   `sudo gedit
   /usr/share/icons/Faenza/index.theme`
2. Locate 3th line from the top. It should look like that `Inherits=gnome,hicolor`
3. Change it to `Inherits=ubuntu-mono-dark,gnome,hicolor`
4. Restart your theme with gnome-tweak-tools or just log out.

If ubuntu does not find suitable icon in faenza icon pack then it will fall back to default ubuntu icon.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post http://handytutorial.com/install-faenza-icons-ubuntu-12-10/ and go to the comments area. It works with me ;).